# Setting an exception cause in Java

Tags: java, exception

I can see on catching an exception that I can print `e.getCause()`, though it is always `null`.

Do I need to set it somewhere, or is something missing which is setting the cause to null?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

An Exception has the attributes `message` and `cause`. The message is a description, telling a human reader more or less exactly, what went wrong. The `cause` is something different: it is, if available, another (nested) `Throwable`.

The concept is often used if we use custom exceptions like this:

```
catch(IOException e) {
  throw new ApplicationException("Failed on reading file soandso", e);
  //                              ^ Message                        ^ Cause
}
```

In response to [djangofan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800629/setting-exception-cause-in-java#comment70512488_5800718):

The standard is that the nested expression (the cause) is printed with its stack trace too.

Running this little application

```
public class Exceptions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exception r = new RuntimeException("Some message");
        throw new RuntimeException("Some other message", r);
    }
}
```

will output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Some other message
    at Exceptions.main(Exceptions.java:4)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some message
    at Exceptions.main(Exceptions.java:3)
    ... 5 more
```

Both messages are included.

Comment: Is it possible to display an exception also showing an additional stack trace of an additional cause?   Isn't that what Vik was really asking?  He wasn't asking: show cause of message,   he was asking: show cause of exception .

Comment: @djangofan - I've added some lines to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 16):

The cause is usually set in the constructor of the exception, e.g. [`Exception(String message, Throwable cause)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29).

If it isn't set in the constructor, you can call [`initCause(Throwable cause)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause%28java.lang.Throwable%29).

Answer (score 3):

class `Exception` has constructors that take a `cause` Throwable. You need to call those constructors or provide constructors to your custom exception classes that call these super constructors.

Answer (score 1):

> **getCause** - Returns the cause of this throwable or null if the cause is nonexistent or unknown. (The cause is the throwable that caused this throwable to get thrown.)

Read the Java documentation: [getCause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause())

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of **null** as the cause
then override toString() method of your *CustomException* class that extends Exception class.

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9355648L;
    public CustomException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Business Exception";
    }
}
```

and

```
throw new CustomException("Stopping further processing.", new CustomException("stale message"));
```

the output is as follows

```
Stopping further processing. Cause : Business Exception
```

for following catch block.

```
} catch (CustomException ce) {
    System.out.print(ce.getMessage());
    System.out.println(" Cause : " + ce.getCause());
}
```