# In java why custom exceptions should also have a constructor with arg as 'Throwable cause'

Tags: java, exception

Can anyone please explain why we should have constructors like below when defining custom exceptions :

```
public MyException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
}

public MyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
}
```

Comment: Catching [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) includes things that subclass [`Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html).

Comment: This allows you to chain the exceptions. Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800629/setting-exception-cause-in-java

Comment: It is not mandatory to have constructors like these. You could have `MyException()` as constructor as well as `MyException(String message)` as constructor. But it is better to have the `Throwable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows you to add to your custom Exception instance information regarding the reason of throwing that exception.

It is useful when you catch one exception and throw another.

For example :

```
try {
    ....
}
catch (SomeException ex) {
    throw new MyException ("some message", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your question one **should** implement the above mentioned constructors to the `MyException` class which is a subclass of `Exception` But it is **not absolutely mandatory** to have only those constructors.

You can very well have the following constructors which do not have `Throwable` as parameters:

```
public MyException() {
    super();
}

public MyException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

But these constructors have a drawback associated. consider the following code say suppose in class `MyClass`:

```
public static void myMethod() throws MyException{
   //Some code
}
```

Now in some code you call this `myMethod()` as show below:

```
try{
   MyClass.myMethod();
} catch (MyException e){
   e.getCause();
}
```

If you used the constructor with the constructors stated in my answer the `e.getCause()` would return `null`. So it would be difficult to ascertain what is the exact cause of the exception.

Comment: could you give me **the reason** why this is a wrong answer and a down vote?