# Spark cannot catch Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE error exception?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I get this Exception while making repartition operation(decreasing partition size).

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE**

While trying to catch this exception somehow below try-catch block doesn't work. It didn't catch the exception.

```
 try{
      someDF.repartition(10)
        .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
        .write.mode("overwrite").format(format).save(temp_location)
    }
    catch {
      case ex: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException => {
      // Do something else
    }
```

But if I make exception type more generic it started to catch exception.

```
 try{
      someDF.repartition(10)
        .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
        .write.mode("overwrite").format(format).save(temp_location)
    }
    catch {
      case ex: Exception => {
      // Do something else
    }
```

So what is the reason behind it?

Does spark somehow throw an other exception internally, different than written as error message?

Answer (score 0):

Note "caused by" in the exception message; it means `IllegalArgumentException` is the *cause* of the exception and you should look at the stack trace before it for the exception class and message itself. It'll look like

```
Exception in thread "<thread-name>" <exception-class>: <message>
```

See also [Setting Exception cause in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800629/setting-exception-cause-in-java) which gives this example stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Some other message
    at Exceptions.main(Exceptions.java:4)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some message
    at Exceptions.main(Exceptions.java:3)
    ... 5 more
```